# Error al llamar un archivo php

Tags: php, html, css

El problema es:

> ```
> Warning: include(../Vistas/plantilla.php): failed to 
> open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\index.php on 
> line 2
> ```

Este es el archivo plantilla.php

```
/*****************************************************************/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php 
include ('../Vistas/Modulos/Head.php');
?>
</head>
<body class="animsition">
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <!-- HEADER MOBILE-->
    <?php 
    include ('../Vistas/Modulos/HeaderMobile.php');
     ?>
    <!-- END HEADER MOBILE-->
    <!-- MENU SIDEBAR-->
    <?php 
    include ('../Vistas/Modulos/MenuSidebar.php');
     ?>
    <!-- END MENU SIDEBAR-->

    <!-- PAGE CONTAINER-->
    <div class="page-container">
        <!-- HEADER DESKTOP-->
        <?php 
        include ('../Vistas/Modulos/HeaderDesktop.php');
         ?>
        <!-- HEADER DESKTOP-->

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT-->
        <?php 
        include ('../Vistas/Modulos/MainContent.php');
         ?>
        <!-- END MAIN CONTENT-->
        <!-- END PAGE CONTAINER-->
    </div>

 </div>
 <?php 
 include ('../Vistas/Modulos/script.php');
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
 <!-- end document-->
```

Y este el el archivo index.php

```
 <?php 
 include ('../Vistas/plantilla.php');
 ?>
```

Comment: ¿Existe el archivo `C:\xampp\htdocs\Vistas/Modulos/Head.php`?

Comment: El archivo esta en C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\Vistas\Modulos\Head.php

Comment: Entonces tienes que usar `./Vistas/Modulos/Head.php` Es con un solo punto.

Comment: Gracias ya me funciona, pero no me lee los estilos correspondientes a la plantilla

Comment: ¿Donde estan los estilos?

Comment: Estarian ubicados en C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\Vistas\css y C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\Vistas\vendor las cuales en la plantilla estarian llamando

Comment: ¿Y la linea de inclusión como esta?

Comment: el archivo que contiene los estilos seria el head.php, y de esta forma estaria dentro. 
 <link href="css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

Comment: Pon `href="/css/theme.css"`

Answer (score 0):

El error:

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

indica que **el fichero que intentas cargar no se encuentra**, por que no esta o por un **problema con las rutas que estás usando para cargar el fichero**, y es independiente del contenido de ese fichero. Si tratas de cargar un fichero con una ruta incorrecta, aunque este esté vacío, tendrás el mismo problema.

Para cargar un fichero PHP puedes comprobar:

**1. Que existe**. Para comprobar si un fichero existe se usa la función [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-exists.php). Si tienes el fichero en disco, pero te indica que no existe, la ruta está mal.

**2. Que tienes acceso, de lectura**, al fichero. Es menos probable que el caso anterior, pero el fichero podría haber sido bloqueado para lectura de algún modo. Se puede comprobar si existe y si puede ser leido con la función [is_readable()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-readable.php).

Por último, **a la hora de trabajar con rutas en el sistema de ficheros**, para evitar problemas se recomienda emplear las [constantes predefinidas](http://php.net/manual/es/language.constants.predefined.php): `__FILE__` y `__DIR__`.